# &amp; replace or decode in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

it is a newbie question. But i spend 3 hours to solve it with 0 result.

i want to convert this link:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/data?make%5B%5D=ACURA&amp;model%5B%5D=LEGEND&amp;score%5B%5D=6
```

in to this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/data?make%5B%5D=ACURA&model%5B%5D=LEGEND&score%5B%5D=6
```

This is my controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $inputRAW    = $request->getQueryString();

        $inputDECODE = htmlspecialchars_decode($inputRAW);

        $input       = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $inputDECODE);

        return view('lots.browse', compact('input'));
    }
```

Some on know what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change query string you should redirect it.

Have a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects

Comment: Hmm.. if . you have time, can you show an example? How can i apply it in my controller?